# What properties does one study for a subset $S$ inside $R = \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and has absorbing property like ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, semigroups

Let us assume that $S \subset\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is non-empty. This set $S$ has the property that $\mathbb{Z}[x] S \subset S$. However, $S$ is not an ideal because sum of two elements from $S$ is not guaranteed to be in $S$.

$S$ is actually a semigroup in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, which amounts to saying that $S S \subset S$, which is weaker than $\mathbb{Z}[x] S \subset S$. I have not studied much about semi-groups; hence this question below:

From what I could find in literature and some searching, one could study elasticity of this semigroup, which is a constant related to the factorization of elements of $S$ into irreducibles of $S$. What other properties of semigroups could one study, given that this is a semigroup of polynomials? If one could direct me to a reference that studies semigroups of polynomials, I would be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: They are also called "ideals" in semigroup theory (you are correct though in your statements above, not the same as ideals of a ring necessarily). The closet thing I can think of immediately from commutative algebra is multiplicative subsets for localization (but that is not quite the same as semigroup ideal). So maybe you might want to look at some semigroup theory directly, because the ideals in there have some ok properties (not quite like groups but there is still a few of the structure theorems).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @yesterday pointed out, your set $S$ is an *ideal* of the multiplicative monoid ${\Bbb Z}[X]$.

It is not too difficult to describe the algebraic structure of this monoid. First observe that the polynomial $0$ is a zero of ${\Bbb Z}[X]$ and that $M = {\Bbb Z}[X] \setminus \{0\}$ is a submonoid of ${\Bbb Z}[X]$.

For each non-zero polynomial $p$, let $c(p)$ denote its  coefficient of higher degree. For instance,
$$
c(-1 -2X + 3X^3) = 3 \quad\text{and}\quad c(1 + X - X^2) = -1
$$
Let $P$ be the set of polynomials $p$ such that $c(p)$ is positive. Let also $I$ be the set of *irreducible polynomials* of $P$. Since ${\Bbb Z}[X]$ is factorial, $P$ is the free commutative monoid generated by $I$, and since $I$ is countable, it is isomorphic to the *additive* monoid $({\Bbb N}[X],+)$.

On the other hand, the set of units of ${\Bbb Z}[X]$ is the cyclic group $U = \{-1, + 1\}$. Finally observe that if $p$ is a non-zero polynomial, then either $p \in P$ or $-p \in P$, depending on the sign of $c(p)$.
I let you verify that in fact, the monoid $M$ is isomorphic to $U \times P$, the product of the monoids $U$ and $P$.

Altogether, ${\Bbb Z}[X]$ is isomorphic to $(U \times ({\Bbb N}[X],+))^0$, the monoid obtained by adjoining a zero to the monoid $U \times ({\Bbb N}[X],+)$.